# How to test if files have been input before by \input

Tags: conditionals, input, external-files

I wonder if there are methods to test if a file(or files) has been input by `\input` before to avoid multiple inputting which may cause `LaTeX Error: Command ... already defined.`

**Example**

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \input{a.tex}
    \input{b.tex}
    
    %#1-files 
    \newcommand\inputfiles[1]{
    %if a certain file in #1 has been input before, then doing noting; else if the file exists then \input this file manually like \iffileexist \input{...}\else warning message and program breaks down\fi.
    }
    % I'd like the macro \inputfiles can work both in preambel and in main document, just like \input.    
    
    \begin{document}
    \inputfiles{a.tex,b.tex,c.tex}
    %Since a.tex and b.tex have been input in preamble, here only c.tex will be input if c.tex exists.
    \end{document}
```

Comment: rename to `.sty` and use `\usepackage{a,b,a,c,b}`  would cover most use cases

Comment: In that case you do need to (or "should") learn how to write packages though. There are guides somewhere

Comment: @David Carlisle, user202729 Would you give an example how to do it?

Comment: @lyl simply look into some other packages. `indentfirst` is a good start: short and to the point.

Comment: @lyl I gave a complete example in my comment. files of definitions should normally be in `.sty` not `.tex` then `\usepackage{a}\usepackage{a}\usepackage{a}\usepackage{a}` will only input `a.sty` once.

Comment: @user202729 no you only need to know how to rename a file from `a.tex` to `a.sty` using your operating system.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then it's a "should".

Comment: @user202729 If you say so. I wouldn't. By design, a file rename is all you need. Of course you need to know how to write definitions, but changing the file name does not change that.

Comment: if there are \makeatletter/\makeatother commands in your files you should better remove them. This is automatic in a  package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer even those don't hurt, they are just not needed. (Major improvement in 2e over 2.09, where a `\makeatletter` at the end of a `.sty` would break all following ones.)

Comment: Ah right, if for whatever reason you write advanced macros in the TeX file and rely on `@` have catcode other, you need to adapt accordingly. Otherwise, no special action is needed

Comment: `\input` can be used anywhere(preamble or main document), but `\usepackage` can only be used in preamble.

Comment: Good point. Edit the question to explain you need to do that...

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer I dont't find `indentfirst.sty` on `CTAN`. In the file `indentfirst.ltx`, there is such a sentence `\GetFileInfo{indentfirst.sty}`. But where to find `indentfirst.sty`?

Comment: @lyl Read  `texdoc docstrip` etc.. Long story short, you can "compile" a dtx file for it to generate a sty file, either by running `[pdf][la]tex file.dtx` or `tex file.ins` (depends on the package)

Comment: Do you really want to input files that do command definitions *after* `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Yes. Because I want to build a general macro to input files not only for those with command definations but also fo  those with other materials.

Comment: But if you input a document with _actual text_ your intent is to include those text, regardless of whether if has been previously included, no? I fail to see the use case here. (Follow best practice and split off any macro definitions into separate files and then load them via `\usepackage`.)

Comment: @ David Carlisle @Ulrike Fischer I rename my `definations.tex`(only contain some definations of macros) to `definations.sty` and remove all `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in it. Then introduce it by `\usepackage{definations}`from my `main.tex`. All the definations by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are not recognized and cause error. Do I miss something?

Comment: If you get an error, something is wrong, but how should we know what? Ask a new question with a proper minimal example and the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the use case, so won't bother expanding the code below to handle comma separated lists of `tex` files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\inputonce[1]{\ifcsdef{prior@input@check#1}{\typeout{#1 already loaded}}{\input{#1}\expandafter\newcommand\csname prior@input@check#1\endcsname{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\input{a}

\input{a}

\inputonce{a}

\inputonce{a}
\end{document}
```

The above code will load `a.tex` a total of three times: the first two times from the `\input{a}`. The third time from the first occurrence of `\inputonce{a}`. The second time `\inputonce{a}` is called the file is not loaded, and a message is shown on the console indicating that the file `a.tex` is already loaded.

Note: this is based on the filename provided to `\input`. So doing `\inputonce{a}` followed by `\inputonce{a.tex}` will not detect the collision.